# Assigning values from an array into variables in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I have a array with 18 elements (may vary, but only is multiples of 6), I want to assign these 18 elements to 6 variables

lets say the array is

array = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18"]

and the variables are

var1, var2, var3, var4, var5, var6

how do I assign the values from the array in to these variables such that for the first time

var1 =1, var2=2, var3=3, var4=4, var5=5, var6=6

and the second time

var1 =7, var2 = 8, var3 = 9, var4 = 10, var5 = 11, var6 = 12

and so on

the length of the array is variables, but it will always be in a multiple of 6

Comment: Frankly, don't. Any time you want to deal with a set of sequentially named variables, you should be using an array in the first place. The smells of being [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: We usually do the opposite. "I have 18 ugly independent variables, how do I arrange them elegantly in an array?"

Comment: You could use [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), e.g. `var [var1, var2, var3, var4, var5, var6] = array; console.log(var4);`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript: Split array into individual variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4671346/javascript-split-array-into-individual-variables)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) your array and use array [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment):

```js
const array = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18"];
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i += 6) {
  const [var1, var2, var3, var4, var5, var6] = array.slice(i, i + 6);
  console.log(var1, var2, var3, var4, var5, var6);
}
```

or better

```js
const array = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18"];
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i += 6) {
  const slice = array.slice(i, i + 6);
  console.log(...slice);
}
```